# Multiple series Issue in line chart using JDBCCategoryDataset

Tags: java, sql, jfreechart

I want to add multiple series to create a line chart using `JFreeChart` in a Java application. I retrieve values from a database and use these values generate a chart. But only one line appears on the chart at the time. Can anyone help in displaying to lines at the same time.?

[image]

```
try{

    String query = "SELECT hardware, SUM(Quantity) FROM request_1v2 where date "
                            + "between '"+txt1+"' and '"+txt2+"'group by hardware";

    String querys = "SELECT hardware, SUM(Quantity) FROM request_1v2 where date "
            + "between '"+txt5+"' and '"+txt6+"'group by hardware";                     

    JDBCCategoryDataset dataset1 = new JDBCCategoryDataset(dbConnection.dbConnector());
    dataset1.executeQuery(query);

    JDBCCategoryDataset dataset2 = new JDBCCategoryDataset(dbConnection.dbConnector());
    dataset2.executeQuery(querys);

    System.out.println(dataset1);

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Hardware booked out between "+txt1+" and "+txt2+"", "Hardware", "Number", dataset1, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, true);
    ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    panel.removeAll();
    panel.add(chartPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.validate();

    JFreeChart chart1 = ChartFactory.createLineChart("Hardware booked out between "+txt5+" and "+txt6+"", "Hardware", "Number", dataset2, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, true);
    ChartPanel chartPanel1 = new ChartPanel(chart1);
    panel_1.removeAll();
    panel_1.add(chartPanel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel_1.validate();

    String sql = "select * from request_1v2 where Date between '"+txt1+"' and '"+txt2+"' order by date desc";
    PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst=connection.prepareStatement(sql);                   
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
}catch (Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, e);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JDBCCategoryDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/jdbc/JDBCCategoryDataset.html) specifies that "The first column will be the category name and remaining columns values (each column represents a series)." To get *two* series, you need to select *three* attributes. It should be possible to use [aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) in a single query to distinguish references to the same table, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7383753/230513), possibly something like this:

```
SELECT hardware, SUM(t1.quantity) AS Series1, SUM(t2.quantity) AS Series2
FROM request_1v2 t1, request_1v2 t2
WHERE t1.date BETWEEN …
```

Alternatively, you can combine the two datasets into new `CategoryDataset` and use it to create a single chart.

```
DefaultCategoryDataset dcd = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
for (int i = 0; i < dataset1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    dcd.addValue(dataset1.getValue(dataset1.getRowKey(0), dataset1.getColumnKey(i)),
        dataset1.getRowKey(0), dataset1.getColumnKey(i));
    dcd.addValue(dataset2.getValue(dataset2.getRowKey(0), dataset2.getColumnKey(i)),
        dataset2.getRowKey(0), dataset1.getColumnKey(i));
}
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createLineChart(…, dcd, …);
```

Comment: Your solution is working but there is a problem that for series 1 I have to use different date and for series 2 I have to use another date. But the query you wrote is only working for the same date. Can you please tell me the query that work on different dates. Like 1st date is for series 1 and 2nd dte is for series 2. Thanks

Comment: I have these two sql statements: Can you combine these two to make it only one:  `String query = "SELECT hardware, SUM(Quantity) FROM request_1v2 where date "
        + "between '"+txt1+"' and '"+txt2+"'group by hardware";
      
      String querys = "SELECT hardware, SUM(Quantity) FROM request_1v2 where date "
        + "between '"+txt5+"' and '"+txt6+"'group by hardware";`

Comment: You can use the same aliases in your `WHERE` clause; I've proposed an alternative above.

Comment: Thanks Sir for your help :)