# Multiple joins on the same table: transition statuses

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a T-SQL table where I have many transition statuses. For every transition pair (AVA_FROM -> AVA_TO) there is a timestamp and I should calculate every duration from status to status. I can't figure how to write a SQL script for my needs.

I wrote here below the sentence for the table creation in SQL Fiddle. Every record with a value in AVA_TO = R-PC is a work start, whilst every record with a value in AVA_FROM = R-PC is a work stop. All the record with the same `AVA_PRIMARYID` belong to the same work order so they need to be summed. Can you help me to solve such problem?

```
CREATE TABLE R5AUDVALUES 
(
    AVA_PRIMARYID nvarchar(8),
    AVA_FROM nvarchar(8),
    AVA_TO nvarchar(8),
    AVA_CHANGED datetime,
    AVA_UPDATED nvarchar(1)
);

INSERT INTO R5AUDVALUES (AVA_PRIMARYID, AVA_FROM, AVA_TO, AVA_CHANGED, AVA_UPDATED) 
VALUES ('44730', 'Q', 'R-PC', '2020-12-14 12:00:00', '+'),
       ('44730', 'R-PC', 'SSP4', '2020-12-14 12:15:00', '+'),
       ('44730', 'SSP4', 'R-PC', '2020-12-14 12:30:00', '+'),
       ('44730', 'R-PC', 'SSP5', '2020-12-14 12:45:00', '+'),
       ('44730', 'SSP5', 'R-PC', '2020-12-14 13:00:00', '+'),
       ('44730', 'R-PC', 'C', '2020-12-14 13:15:00', '+')
```

The result should be like the following :

```
WorkOrder, WorkStart,            WorkStop 
'44730',   2020-12-14 12:00:00', '2020-12-14 12:15:00',
'44730',   2020-12-14 12:30:00', '2020-12-14 12:45:00',
'44730',   2020-12-14 13:00:00', '2020-12-14 13:15:00'
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: Maybe the lead function can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataset is regular then just `row_number()` and join.

```
with c as (
  select AVA_PRIMARYID, AVA_FROM, AVA_TO, AVA_CHANGED, AVA_UPDATED, row_number()over (order by AVA_CHANGED) n
  from R5AUDVALUES
 )
 select a.*, b.AVA_CHANGED, datediff(minute, a.AVA_CHANGED, b.AVA_CHANGED) minutes
 from c a
 join c b on a.n+1 = b.n and a.AVA_TO = 'R-PC' and  b.AVA_FROM = 'R-PC'
```

Otherwise you may need a data cleaning step first.

[db<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8c23f1e724da685e5b565aaaceceee21)

Comment: Thanks, it works, but I have 2 more problems : "with" statement doesn't work on my reporting engine and row_number() too. In my reporting engine there is a "graphic" "running-count" but I don't know if that is the same.

Comment: @over, tag your question with specific tags. My solution is for `sql-server`.

Comment: Ok, my database is sql-server and it works in SQL Fiddle as I expected, but for some strange reason the "with" statement doesn't work on my report engine... don't know why.

Comment: @over, if your engine  sends `with` in a batch, previous command in the batch must be terminated with semicolon. Try `;with ..`

Comment: I already tested few days ago ";with...." and "with" since another user on another topic gave me a "with" suggestion and I thought the semicolon was a typo. Since that query did not work, I started to try very light basic "with" statement (with and without semicolon as start char) and the result was only cryptic errors coming out from Cognos Advanced Reporting.

Comment: @over, I recommend you open another question on Cognos Advanced Reporting behaviour.

Comment: I didn't give up and googled more about the strange behavior of Cognos. Finally I found an "hidden"  tip for the reporting engine setting and ... voila'. Your query is now working. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I can't undertand how the "double alias" works (i.e. you wrote ...from c a... or join c b...) This is the first time I see in a query statement. Can you point me to some more info about ? Thanks

Comment: Please see this topic for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7383753/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-table-twice-in-a-select-query

Comment: I tested more the statement you provide me but there are some problems; I added more record with different AVA_PRYMARYID and datetime in between the previous AVA_PRYMARY; the result get mixed, moreover I need to filter a specific AVA_PRIMARYID and I couldn't.  I've added the following records to my previous dataset : 

 ('44740', 'Q', 'R-PC', '2020-12-14 13:01:00', '+'),
 ('44740', 'R-PC', 'C', '2020-12-14 13:45:00', '+')
 
 See also your db<>fiddle

Comment: I can't understand also where is the definition of "a.*" ...I know is bound to R5AUDVALUES but I can't see where is the definition of that. Thanks.

Comment: I played with "order by" in the row_number() function and got my correct result, anyway I still can't understand where is the "a" table definition in the sql statement. Bye.